# Issue with file names and content that includes foreign characters

Tags: c, string, encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to write a program that fetches the name and contents of a text file (UTF-8).
I use

```
system("chcp 65001 > nul");
```

to be able to properly read foreign characters in the text and copy them to a string one character at a time. The characters get properly copied to the string.

I also want to get the name of the file which includes Turkish characters such as İ, Ö, Ç, Ü etc.

For this I use strcpy with dir->d_name

The issue is when I print them to the terminal text contents are fine but file name is missing afromentioned foreign characters.

```
"TRKE.txt" instead of "TÜRKÇE.txt"
```

I must be able to accurately compare the file contents with file name using strcmp but it's not possible since the name is missing characters.

Using

```
system("chcp 1254 > nul");
```

instead makes it possible to get the file name correctly but then the contents of the file are not represented correctly. Alternating between the two lines doesn't work since I need both to be working at the same time to use strcmp().

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");
```

doesn't fix it either. What do I do?

Comment: When the characters are missing after printing them to the terminal it is probably your terminals fault. Comparing the strings in C should be fine.

Comment: strcmp just compares bytes up to the first Null. It neither knows nor cares what encoding they use